# How to get SESSIONID out of string?

Tags: python

I have this string, I need to get the `TNS_SESSIONID` out of it, so the string looks like this:

```
<RequestsCookieJar[<Cookie TNS_SESSIONID=a2d97bb215e39414f14a654580cb27c3 for www.xxx.net/>]>
```

I need this value: `a2d97bb215e39414f14a654580cb27c3`.

Below is my code but it only gives numbers instead of letters, I want the whole thing. Any suggestions?

```
ses = (str(response.cookies))
session =''.join(filter(str.isdigit, ses))
print (session)
```

Comment: Why convert `response.cookes` to a string?

Comment: I don't have to, but doesn't know a better way to get the  TNS_SESSIONID out of the cookiejar.

Comment: you are right, that was simple : )! Thanks a lot Barmar!

Answer (score 1):

Just read the cookie directly from the `cookies` dictionary:

```
session = response.cookies['TNS_SESSIONID']
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not convert the response into str `ses = (str(response.cookies))`

```
cookies = response.cookies.get_dict()
TNS_SESSIONID = cookies.get("TNS_SESSIONID")
print(TNS_SESSIONID)
```